# Current URL string parser is deprecated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, body-parser

when I run the code by "node app.js" command this error is showing

(node:2509) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

Comment: it's a warning. Also, it gives you the information to fix it. I'm not sure what you are asking

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to pass `{ useNewUrlParser: true }` option to mongoose.connect() method. Your code should look similar to the snippet below.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pw@host1.com:27017/dbname', { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

Comment: when I make this it gives me error <code> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): [object Object]
(node:7) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. </code> even I didn't mention anything related to promise

Comment: @palAlaa I am getting the same error when passing the { useNewUrlParser: true } in as the second param between `url` and `callback`

Answer (score 5):

to avoid this problem use this

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://user:password@sample.com:port/dbname', { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

Comment: in which file should I use this snippet?

Answer (score 0):

For those having this message "DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.  even I didn't mention anything related to promise"

I pasted the code the error gets fixed with in the following link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52459082/10399142